# Using the same node / instance on all build jobs in a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

pipeline {
agent { label 'linux' }

```
stages{
    stage("verify1"){
        steps {
            script {
                build(job: "verfiy1", parameters: [string(name: 'verfiy1', value: "${params.verfiy1}")])
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage("verify2"){
        steps {
            script {
                build(job: "verfiy2", parameters: [string(name: 'verfiy2', value: "${params.verfiy2}")])
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage("verify3"){
        steps {
            script {
                build(job: "verify3", parameters: [string(name: 'verify3', value: "${params.verify3}")])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

=================================================================

Hello

can anyone help me, right now from the above pipeline i am able to build 3 jobs sucessfull but the problem is every single job is executing on new ec2 slave instance instead of the instance where the job has started. I am expecting the output as once the above pipeline starts all the builds in the pipeline must execute on the same node (ec2 instance).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `verify x` job is freestyle job or also a pipeline as script?

Comment: it is pipeline job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the upstream job's agent node to the downstream job.

1. Add one more job parameter to accept node
2. Pass upstream job's agent node via `env.NODE_NAME` when call `build job` step

```
// verify 1 job

pipeline {
   agent { label "${params.agentNode}" }
   parameters {
      string(name: "agentNode", 
             defaultValue="<give default value in case run it directly>" )
   }
}

// upstream job

build(job: "verify1", parameters: [
    string(name: 'agentNode', value: "${env.NODE_NAME}"),
    string(name: 'verify3', value: "${params.verify3}")
])
```

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for the revert.

I have tried the above way and declared label "${params.agentNode}" in the build jobs pipelines verfiy1, 2 & 3, where it assigns env.NODE_NAME value from the main job to downstream build jobs verify 1,2,3 using the parameters. This way it kept on looking for the node which it couldn't find.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the agent label 'linux' is a group machine,  the upstream job pick one from the group to build itself, but every machine in the group is not labeled, thus the downsteam job can not find the machine by label: env.NODE_NAME